# unable to install mysqlclient for django using pip3 in ubuntu

Tags: python, django, mysql-connector

**command:** sudo -H pip3 install mysqlclient

**Error:**

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-b0rfercj
/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lck3vdnw-record
/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip-build-b0rfercj/mysqlclient/
```

I have already install python3-dev

```
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed `libssl` and `libcrypto`?

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```